# How do I access an object response (rather than a list) in jqueryui autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, flask

I have a jqueryui autocomplete function I am trying to implement and the following returned results:

```
{'returned_results':[{'label':'red','value':'Fred'},{'label':'blue','value':'Marie'}] }
```

If it was just a list of objects the below code would work but since I am using Flask it will not let me jsonify a list, so I need to put the results in a dictionary/object. How do I access 'returned_results'?

```
function tickerFormatter(){
   $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function(ul,item){
       var re = new RegExp(this.term,"i");
       var l = item.label;
       var v = item.value;
       .... 
       return $("<li></li>")
       .data('item.autocomplete',item)
       .append('<a>' + l + ':&nbsp;' + v + '</a>')
       .appendTo(ul);
   };
} 

$(function(){
    tickerFormatter();
     $("#tickers").autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: '/my_api?',
    select: function(event,ui){
      ....

    }
   })

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one of two things:

1. Change `source` to use the [`function` form](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source):

   ```
   $("#tickers").autocomplete({
     minLength: 1,
     source: function(request, callback) {
       $.getJSON('/my_api', request,
           function(data) {
             callback(data.returned_results);
       });
     }
   });
   ```
2. Return your own custom response, using [`make_response`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.make_response):

   ```
   import json
   from flask import make_response

   # Then in your controller
   response = make_response(json.dumps(list_of_results))
   response['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
   return response
   ```

Comment: wow, two great answers. I haven't tried the second one but the first one works great! thx!